# TopsvilleNFT ,took 2000.00 and suspended my account for asking where was the 50eth they sent to paypal om 11/16/23

Tags: transactions

I joined topvillenft and payed a gas fee and withdrawal fee. on 11/16/23 they said they sent 50eth to my paypal account. I called after it was never recieved. The man said at topvillenft that opps, he forgot to tell me ,of additional fees of 3400.00 cfredit card fees. I was scammed and defrauded 2000.00

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your experience. Unfortunately, fraudulent activities like this are prevalent in the crypto space, the money is hard to recover.